# Google Sheets XML path returns no data

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

Using the following in Google Sheets:

`IMPORTXML("http://www.fishingnotes.com/fishing-report/al/Lake-Purdy","//div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]")`

I should receive the result:

41° (What's This)
 but instead Google says Imported Content is Empty

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=index(IMPORTXML("http://www.fishingnotes.com/fishing-report/al/Lake-
Purdy","//span[2][@id='atemp']"),1,1)
```

It will return 41°

Or use

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.fishingnotes.com/fishing-report/al/Lake-
Purdy","//span[2][@id='atemp']")
```

to return 41°   (What's This)

Comment: Perfect. But why the index?

Comment: Without index, two cells are returned 41° in one cell and (What's This) in the cell to the right. Try the second =importxlm above without index and you will see this. Index gets just the first row and first column which is 41°. I assumed that was what you really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this xpath: //tr[3]/td/text() will be the simplest way to get the degrees:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.fishingnotes.com/fishing-report/al/Lake-Purdy","//tr[3]/td/text()")
```